# OpenLDAP Cluster

Tags: proxy, cluster, openldap, high-availability, redundancy

Trying to implement an OpenLDAP cluster, I already managed to set up the two backend LDAP servers in mirroring mode.

The application (iRedMail) using the LDAP service is running on the same systems as the LDAP servers. This applications needs the LDAP configuration in the former slapd.conf manner and not in the CONFIG-DB way. So I added the mirroring parameters to the slapd.conf file. The file looks like this on the first backend node:

```
include     /etc/openldap/schema/core.schema
include     /etc/openldap/schema/corba.schema
include     /etc/openldap/schema/cosine.schema
include     /etc/openldap/schema/inetorgperson.schema
include     /etc/openldap/schema/nis.schema
include     /etc/openldap/schema/calentry.schema
include     /etc/openldap/schema/calresource.schema
include     /etc/openldap/schema/amavisd-new.schema
include     /etc/openldap/schema/iredmail.schema

pidfile     /var/run/openldap/slapd.pid
argsfile    /var/run/openldap/slapd.args

# The syncprov overlay
moduleload syncprov.la

disallow    bind_anon
require     LDAPv3
loglevel    0

access to attrs="userPassword,mailForwardingAddress,employeeNumber"
    by anonymous    auth
    by self         write
    by dn.exact="cn=vmail,dc=myCompany,dc=de"   read
    by dn.exact="cn=vmailadmin,dc=myCompany,dc=de"  write
    by users        none

access to attrs="cn,sn,gn,givenName,telephoneNumber"
    by anonymous    auth
    by self         write
    by dn.exact="cn=vmail,dc=myCompany,dc=de"   read
    by dn.exact="cn=vmailadmin,dc=myCompany,dc=de"  write
    by users        read

access to attrs="objectclass,domainName,mtaTransport,enabledService,domainSenderBccAddress,domainRecipientBccAddress,domainBackupMX,domainMaxQuotaSize,domainMaxUserNumber,domainPendingAliasName"
    by anonymous    auth
    by self         read
    by dn.exact="cn=vmail,dc=myCompany,dc=de"   read
    by dn.exact="cn=vmailadmin,dc=myCompany,dc=de"  write
    by users        read

access to attrs="domainAdmin,domainGlobalAdmin,domainSenderBccAddress,domainRecipientBccAddress"
    by anonymous    auth
    by self         read
    by dn.exact="cn=vmail,dc=myCompany,dc=de"   read
    by dn.exact="cn=vmailadmin,dc=myCompany,dc=de"  write
    by users        none

access to attrs="mail,accountStatus,domainStatus,userSenderBccAddress,userRecipientBccAddress,mailQuota,backupMailAddress,shadowAddress,memberOfGroup,member,uniqueMember,storageBaseDirectory,homeDirectory,mailMessageStore,mailingListID"
    by anonymous    auth
    by self         read
    by dn.exact="cn=vmail,dc=myCompany,dc=de"   read
    by dn.exact="cn=vmailadmin,dc=myCompany,dc=de"  write
    by users        read

access to dn="cn=vmail,dc=myCompany,dc=de"
    by anonymous                    auth
    by self                         write
    by users                        none

access to dn="cn=vmailadmin,dc=myCompany,dc=de"
    by anonymous                    auth
    by self                         write
    by users                        none

access to dn.regex="domainName=([^,]+),o=domains,dc=myCompany,dc=de$"
    by anonymous                    auth
    by self                         write
    by dn.exact="cn=vmail,dc=myCompany,dc=de"   read
    by dn.exact="cn=vmailadmin,dc=myCompany,dc=de"  write
    by dn.regex="mail=[^,]+@$1,o=domainAdmins,dc=myCompany,dc=de$" write
    by dn.regex="mail=[^,]+@$1,ou=Users,domainName=$1,o=domains,dc=myCompany,dc=de$" read
    by users                        none

access to dn.subtree="o=domains,dc=myCompany,dc=de"
    by anonymous                    auth
    by self                         write
    by dn.exact="cn=vmail,dc=myCompany,dc=de"    read
    by dn.exact="cn=vmailadmin,dc=myCompany,dc=de"  write
    by users                        read

access to dn.subtree="o=domainAdmins,dc=myCompany,dc=de"
    by anonymous                    auth
    by self                         write
    by dn.exact="cn=vmail,dc=myCompany,dc=de"    read
    by dn.exact="cn=vmailadmin,dc=myCompany,dc=de"  write
    by users                        none

access to dn.regex="cn=[^,]+,dc=myCompany,dc=de"
    by anonymous                    auth
    by self                         write
    by users                        none

access to *
    by anonymous                    auth
    by self                         write
    by users                        read

database monitor
access to dn="cn=monitor"
    by dn.exact="cn=Manager,dc=myCompany,dc=de" read
    by dn.exact="cn=vmail,dc=myCompany,dc=de" read
    by * none

database    mdb
suffix      dc=myCompany,dc=de
directory   /var/lib/ldap/myCompany.de
rootdn      cn=Manager,dc=myCompany,dc=de
rootpw      {SSHA}V5/UQXm9SmzRGjKK2zAKB79eFSaysc2wG9tPIg==
sizelimit   unlimited
maxsize     2147483648
checkpoint  128 3
mode        0700

index objectclass,entryCSN,entryUUID                eq
index uidNumber,gidNumber,uid,memberUid,loginShell  eq,pres
index homeDirectory,mailMessageStore                eq,pres
index ou,cn,mail,surname,givenname,telephoneNumber,displayName  eq,pres,sub
index nisMapName,nisMapEntry                        eq,pres,sub
index shadowLastChange                              eq,pres
index member,uniqueMember eq,pres

index domainName,mtaTransport,accountStatus,enabledService,disabledService  eq,pres,sub
index domainAliasName    eq,pres,sub
index domainMaxUserNumber eq,pres
index domainAdmin,domainGlobalAdmin,domainBackupMX    eq,pres,sub
index domainSenderBccAddress,domainRecipientBccAddress  eq,pres,sub

index accessPolicy,hasMember,listAllowedUser,mailingListID   eq,pres,sub

index mailForwardingAddress,shadowAddress   eq,pres,sub
index backupMailAddress,memberOfGroup   eq,pres,sub
index userRecipientBccAddress,userSenderBccAddress  eq,pres,sub
index mobile,departmentNumber eq,pres,sub

#Mirror Mode
serverID    001

# Consumer
syncrepl rid=001 \
provider=ldap://rm2.myCompany.de \
bindmethod=simple \
binddn="cn=vmail,dc=myCompany,dc=de" \
credentials="gtV9FwILIcp8Zw8YtGeB1AC9GbGfti" \
searchbase="dc=myCompany,dc=de" \
attrs="*,+" \
type=refreshAndPersist \
interval=00:00:01:00 \
retry="60 +"
# Provider
overlay syncprov
syncprov-checkpoint 50 1
syncprov-sessionlog 50

mirrormode on
```

There are only two differences in the second node's config file:

```
[...]
#Mirror Mode
serverID    002
[...]

# Consumer
[...]
provider=ldap://rm2.myCompany.de \
[...]
```

As mentioned before the mirroring works perfectly.

Now I need a single connection address for the LDAP clients, i.e. web applications using LDAP as authentication mechanism.

I read that you can use an OpenLDAP proxy for that purpose. The LDAP client (here: web application) connects to the LDAP proxy and the proxy will retrieve the authentication data from multiple backend LDAP servers.

I set up an OpenLDAP proxy, it uses CONFIG-DB, not the ancient way. The slapd.conf file looks like this:

```
include         /etc/openldap/schema/corba.schema
include         /etc/openldap/schema/core.schema
include         /etc/openldap/schema/cosine.schema
include         /etc/openldap/schema/duaconf.schema
include         /etc/openldap/schema/dyngroup.schema
include         /etc/openldap/schema/inetorgperson.schema
include         /etc/openldap/schema/java.schema
include         /etc/openldap/schema/misc.schema
include         /etc/openldap/schema/nis.schema
include         /etc/openldap/schema/openldap.schema
include         /etc/openldap/schema/ppolicy.schema

pidfile         /var/run/openldap/slapd.pid
argsfile        /var/run/openldap/slapd.args

modulepath  /usr/lib/openldap
modulepath  /usr/lib64/openldap
moduleload  back_ldap.la       
loglevel    0

database        ldap
readonly        yes            
protocol-version    3
rebind-as-user
uri         "ldap://rm1.myCompany.de:389"
suffix              "dc=myCompany,dc=de"
uri                     "ldap://rm2.myCompany.de:389"
suffix              "dc=myCompany,dc=de"
```

First issue:

Creating the CONFIG-DB using slaptest, the command fails, claiming:

```
5dc44107 /etc/openldap/slapd.conf: line 48: suffix already served by this backend!.
slaptest: bad configuration directory!
```

The slaptest command looks like this:

```
slaptest -f /etc/openldap/slapd.conf -F /etc/openldap/slapd.d/
```

It is possible that I didn't understand completely the concept, because all guides I found are using subdomain prefixes for the different LDAP backend servers, i.e. instead of:

```
uri         "ldap://rm1.myCompany.de:389"
suffix              "dc=myCompany,dc=de"
uri                     "ldap://rm2.myCompany.de:389"
suffix              "dc=myCompany,dc=de"
```

they use:

```
uri            "ldap://rm1.myCompany.de:389"
suffix         "dc=ou1,dc=myCompany,dc=de"
uri            "ldap://rm2.myCompany.de:389"
suffix         "dc=ou2,dc=myCompany,dc=de"
```

What I didn't understand: On the backend servers there is no ou1 and ou2 respectively. How can they expect to find anything in the backend LDAPs if the DNs do not match?

I temporarily commented the second uri in order to check if, apart from this issue, LDAP queries to the LDAP proxy succeed, but ran into the second issue.

Second issue:

If I run an ldapsearch against directly to the two backend LDAP servers (one after the other), all of the LDAP users will be enumerated.

If I run the same ldapsearch against the LDAP proxy, only the user "vmail" will be enumerated. I think that the same users should be listed as in the direct query.

This is the ldapsearch command:

```
ldapsearch -D "cn=vmail,dc=myCompany,dc=de" -w gtV9FwILIcp8Zw8YtGeB1AC9GbGfti -p 389 -h 192.168.0.92 -b "dc=myCompany,dc=de" -s sub "(objectclass=person)"
```

Did I miss sth.?

Thank you for your considerations!

Best regards,
Florian